# How to include JS in a page HTML with Apache Sling

Tags: osgi-bundle, apache-felix, sling

In Apache Sling i want include a javascript into a HTML page.
Via http://localhost:8080/bin/browser.html/ I created two nodes (then manually): html.html and processing.js.
JSON of html.html is:

```
{
  "jcr:created": "{Date}2018-04-19 20:50:09",
  "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
  "jcr:primaryType": "{Name}nt:file",
  "jcr:content": {
    "jcr:data": "/bin/cpm/nodes/property.bin/apps/res/html.html/_jcr_content?name=jcr%3Adata",
    "jcr:lastModified": "{Date}2018-04-19 20:50:09",
    "jcr:lastModifiedBy": "admin",
    "jcr:mimeType": "text/html",
    "jcr:primaryType": "{Name}nt:resource",
    "jcr:uuid": "ed3121b3-580c-46b2-acc6-7029cdb6f1c3"
  }
}
```

JSON of processing.js is:

```
{
  "jcr:data": "/bin/cpm/nodes/property.bin/apps/res/processing.js?name=jcr%3Adata",
  "jcr:lastModified": "{Date}2018-04-19 21:32:40",
  "jcr:lastModifiedBy": "admin",
  "jcr:mimeType": "text/javascript",
  "jcr:primaryType": "{Name}nt:resource",
  "jcr:uuid": "74fd137a-3b37-4893-b443-bd086a4fb4d7"
}
```

In page HTML I include processing.js with <script> tag in the <head> tag look like following:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="processing.js"></script>
</head>
```

Both nodes is located on the same path, that's "apps".

I get error in console of Mozilla Firefox:

[image: Error Mozilla Firefox]http://i68.tinypic.com/a0cj88.png

In error.log file I get this error:

```
19.04.2018 22:13:32.813 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1524168812811] GET /apps/processing.js HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Resource /apps/processing.js not found
```

Why did I get this error? How can i fix it?
Please help me. Thanks you very much in advance.

Comment: Up. I'm thinking that this happen because the script tag isn't interpreted by Sling, but from browser, that then will search resource and not finding it (because it is in form of node, not identified from browser). But I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: I solved. I inserted the js into etc folder and i pointed in it into html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the resource path to the src of your file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource.path}/processing.js"></script>
```

THat should solve the problem